# insert values from equal arrays using WITH PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I would like smth like:

```
INSERT INTO Transit (idProc, uuidSeg, number) 
select * from 
unnest(array[2, 2]), 
unnest(array ['3ec172b9-b99f-43e2-83bb-527e9b0fb308', '6a72c69c-1083-4c63-83ec-22b0ab512789']::uuid[]), 
unnest(array[1, 2]) where 'some_value' IS NOT NULL;
```

But this query inserts too many rows:

[image]

Inserts correct when I run

```
WITH data (idProc, uuidSeg, number)  as
    (VALUES
      (2, '3ec172b9-b99f-43e2-83bb-527e9b0fb308'::uuid, 1),
      (2, '6a72c69c-1083-4c63-83ec-22b0ab512789'::uuid, 2))
INSERT INTO Transit (idProc, uuidSeg, number)
SELECT d.idProc, d.uuidSeg, d.number
FROM data d
WHERE 'some_value' is not null;
```

[image]

My question is, What way I can rewrite my first query for it would be possible to insert correctly from arrays simultaneously (they are always **equal**)? In fact, first column (idProc) is not an array, it is a value, that must be inserted so many times as the length of array. Is it possible?

Comment: `WHERE 'some_value' is not null;` is always true: 'some_value' is a string literal.

Comment: 'some_value' I mean parametric value from Python script (%s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unnest()` can take multiple arguments, unnesting them in parallel:

```
select *  
from unnest(array[2, 2], 
            array ['3ec172b9-b99f-43e2-83bb-527e9b0fb308', '6a72c69c-1083-4c63-83ec-22b0ab512789']::uuid[], 
            array[1, 2]
           ) u(idProc, uuidSeg, number)
where 'some_value' IS NOT NULL;
```